# Java - Which types of classes are these; which is the anonymous inner class?

Tags: java, actionlistener, inner-classes, anonymous-inner-class

I've read several online articles which contradict each other. I thought this would be an example of an anonymous inner class:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerfored(ActionEvent e) {
       // do something.
    }
});
```

However, I've also seen this described as an anonymous inner class:

```
ActionListener myListener = new ActionListener() { 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
          // do something.
    }
};
button.addActionListener(myListener);
```

Which is which, and why? Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both of them are. The second one is just assigned to a variable before being added as an action listener.

This is the same as the difference between

```
myList.add(new String("myString"));
```

and

```
String s = new String("myString");
myList.add(s);
```

it has nothing to do with anonymous classes.

Comment: as a note the second one might be useful if you want to use the same action listener for multiple buttons.

Comment: One should mention that both are anonymous inner classes because the _classes_ have no name (which has nothing to do with the names of instances).

Comment: @Anthales Why are they called anonymous classes if the second has a reference to the ActionListener though? Why is it anonymous if it has this reference?

Comment: @Tim The `Class` has no name associated with it is what makes it anonymous (`ActionListener` is an `Interface` not a `Class`), not whether or not the `instance` (in this case `myListener`) has a name.

Comment: As @Anthales said, the class doesn't have a name; if you wanted a non-anonymous class, you'd have to do `class MyClass implements ActionListener { ... }`; this class would be called `MyClass`. In Anonymous classes, you define a class with new methods in it, but it doesn't have a name - we just know that it inherits from `ActionListener`

Comment: @Richante, then what exactly is the myListener reference? And is it not essentially creating a new ActionListener object?

Comment: @Tim ActionListener is an interface; if you try to do `myListener = new ActionListener();` you will get an error, because ActionListener is not a class. If you want an object that implements ActionListener, you need to provide code for `void ActionPerformed`. To do this non-anonymously, you have to write a new class like `MyClass` in my previous comment. As an alternative, you can give code for `void ActionPerformed` at the same time as you construct an instance. [This](http://inheritingjava.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/chapter-54-anonymous-inner-classes.html) seems to be a decent tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Both are anonymous inner classes. In the second case you are storing a reference to the anonymous class just so that you can call some methods on it later.

Answer (score 0):

Like Richante said, they both are.

Think about it, they both are unnamed and are defined inside another class.

Answer (score 0):

Both are actually examples of Anonymous inner class. In First example, anonymous inner class is provided when passing an argument to addActionListener() method. In second example a reference to anonymous inner class is created.